# Combining different svg fill symbols in QGIS without overlapping

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to get a polygon filled with a couple of different SVG fills without overlapping?

I want them to go side by side forming a mosaic, instead of overlapping each other, but can't find how (of if) I can do that. I guess there should be something like an offset option, but there's no such thing on SVG fill tab, or I don't know how to find it.